# Using Java and USB: Which API to use? jsr-80, jusb, ...?

Tags: java, api, usb, jusb

I would like two Java programs to communicate directly over USB without going through a device or cable.  Don't ask me why, I don't know the details or reasoning behind this decision.

I have found jusb and jsr-80 to be two Java/USB APIs to do this.  They work on Linux and Windows - I will need capabilities on both.

Which is more standard and accepted?  Which is more stable?  Which is easier for my task?  Are there other standard or common Java/USB APIs out there?

I'd like to hear your guys' experiences with these or other Java/USB APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Well both of these implementations have their limitations specially on windows. They both lack support for Bulk Transfer on windows.

There is a commercial library JCommUSB available at www.icaste.com

Answer (score 0):

> I would like two java programs to communicate directly over the USB without going through a device or cable

Huh? USB connects a device to a host via a cable.

edit: If I had to quickly use two Java programs to communicate, one on a device and one on a host, I would almost certainly use the USB link (configured that way outside of the scope of Java) to act as a serial stream and use a serial library like [rxtx](http://rxtx.org/).