# How to run Java USB API for Windows using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, usb

I understand that there is no complete support for USB for Java in Windows. But jUSB provides a Java USB API for windows which does not provide support for the complete functionality though.

I am trying to install the Java USB API and try it, and the steps provided say he following,

jUSB DLL
Copy the jusb.dll from the folder \InstallationFiles\JusbDll to the \system32 folder
of your Windows directory.
Compile the usb.windows package in Netbeans. Attach a USB device to the
USB and run RunUSBControllerTest.

I am a novice java user, and I currently work with Eclipse. I do not understand what to compile and how to run RunUSBControllerTest alone. Could someone please tell me how to run the application using Eclipse.

http://www.steelbrothers.ch/jusb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other question in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444497/using-java-and-usb-which-api-jsr-80-jusb-) like this.

I recommended you:

- Learn java before fight with this more complex and undocumented topic.
- Use standards APIs like [JSR-80](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=80). This standard could be a good search start point.

See this thread in [forum.java.net](http://forums.java.net/jive/message.jspa?messageID=338945)

I hope this helps and good luck.